# Find the probability that between 5 random digits appear two differents.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have the following exercise;
Find the probability that in five random digits appear;

a) two differents.

My approach was the following.

I consider for example the vector $(1,1,1,1,0)$ and noted that all different strings with 4's ones and 1 zero is $\binom{5}{1}$, then as I can select $(10)(9)$ pairs of different digits, all the cases of this form are $10(9)\binom{5}{1}$.

Next, I consider for example the vector $(1,1,1,0,0)$ and noted that all  that all different strings with 3's ones and 2 zero is $\binom{5}{2}$ then as I can select $(10)(9)$ pairs of different digits, all the cases of this form are $10(9)\binom{5}{2}$.

I have not to consider the vectors of the form $(1,1,0,0,0)$ because the number of those vectors are considered in the inmediately previous case. The same applies for the vectors of the form $(0,0,0,0,1)$

Certainly, the total of cases is $10^5$

So the probability that we are looking for is

$$P(A)=\dfrac{10(9)\binom{5}{1}+ 10(9)\binom{5}{2}  }{10^5}$$.

Am I correct?

Is there a faster way of do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Slight typo at the end, one of the $\binom{5}{2}$ should be $\binom{5}{1}$. Otherwise fine, if we want the probability of exactly $2$ different digits. I do not think there is a more efficient way.